# How can I interrupt a synchronized statement in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, synchronized

I have two threads that want to synchonize on the same object. Thead `A` needs to be able to interrupt Thread `B` if a certain condition has been fullfilled. Here is some pseudo-code of what the two threads do/should do.

#### A:

```
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        //Do stuff
        synchronized(shared)
        {
            //Do more stuff
            if(condition)
            {
                B.interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### B:

```
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            //Do stuff
            synchronized(shared)
            {
            //Do more stuff
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the situation I can't resolve:

- Thread `A` grabs the shared resource and does some stuff.
- Meanwhile, Thread `B` reaches the synchronized block, and awaits for `A` to release its shared resource.
- Thread `A`, while doing stuff, realized that Thread B should not have the shared resource, and tries to interrupt Thread `B`. But Thread `B` has already surpassed the points where an `InterruptedException` could be thrown.

My question is, is there any way to interrupt a thread while it is waiting to be `synchronized` on something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this kind of thing, you should use the classes in [`java.util.concurrent.locks`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-frame.html) - they have far more capabilities, including interruptable locks.

**Edit:** If you cannot use those classes, then look at jkff's answer - your requirements can be met with the `wait()`/`notify()` mechnism, but it's easy to introduce subtle bugs.

Comment: I was afraid that that might be the solution: I'm working with a subset of Java, which doesn't have those classes by default. Are they pure Java (in which case I could include them anyway), or do they require native libraries (a no-go)?

Comment: It's pure Java, introduced in Java 1.5

Comment: @Eric, what subset?  Is it j2me?

Comment: @Valentin: I wouldn't be 100% certain about that. It might be true for the locks, but the java.util.concurrent.atomic classes definitely use native stuff (though they're specified in a way that they can be implemented less efficiently in pure Java, the JDK source code uses native calls).

Comment: @finnw: No. I'm using LeJOS NXJ, a Java language for the Lego Mindstorms NXT Microcontroller.

Comment: if it's of any help, here is a backport of java.util.concurrent for JVM without it : http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/index.php (I don't know however if it will work with yours)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed you should use the locks or implement your stuff with the `Object.wait()`, `Object.notify()` and `Object.notifyAll()` methods (locks are actually implemented with them). Do not forget to handle the so-called 'spurious wakeups' (`wait()` may return even if noone called `notify()` or `notifyAll()`, so it should always be called in a loop that checks that the condition you're waiting for is satisfied).

Answer (score 1):

No, but `ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly()` behaves similarly to the primitive `monitorenter` instruction and can be interrupted.